# Can this set be not separable ? Can it be not compact?

Tags: probability-theory, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, simplex, separable-spaces

Let $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X)$ be a measure space, let $\mathcal S_X=\{ q : (\mathcal X, \Sigma_X, q)\text{ is a probability space}\}$, i.e. the simplex associated to $(\mathcal X,\Sigma_X)$. We equip $\mathcal S_X$ with the weakest topology such that for all bounded measurable $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$, the function $p\to p(f)\triangleq\int_{\mathcal X}f ~dp$ is continuous. This is a bounded, closed convex subset of a Hausdorff locally convex vector space. I believe that in general, this set is non separable and non compact, however I could not find an example, I think that we need $\Sigma_X$ to be big enough of an infinite set, having $\mathcal X$ infinite is not enough.

I have tried few example, including $\mathcal X=[0,1]$ and $\Sigma_X$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, but I think this might actually be both compact and separable, I am not sure on how to show that either. Any input would be very useful.

Comment: For measurable $f$ the integral $\int f\,dq$ is not necessarily well-defined. Do you mean to take bounded measurable $f$?

Comment: This topology seems to be rather strong, for example $p(\{x\})$ must be a continuous function of $p$ for each $x\in X$. Does it really make your latter example into a separable space of measures?

Comment: @MaoWao yes indeed, I want $f$ to be bounded.

Comment: @llya Yes actually that is perfect, we can therefore say that the space is not separable and therefore it should be fairly simple to show it is not compact, I think that answers both my questions.

Comment: @P.Quinton the usual way the weak topology (e.g. for convergence in distribution in probability) is defined on a space of measures is not by taking it with respect to _all bounded_ measurable functions, but rather with respect to either of the set of all _continuous functions with compact support_, _continuous functions that vanish at infinity_, _bounded continuous functions._ For many nice spaces (separable, metrizable and locally compact), the topology defined in either way coincide.

Comment: @WilliamM. But I guess all of that would be by making some additional assumption on $\mathcal X$ and $\Sigma_X$ right ? in particular if $\mathcal X$ is a vector space and $\Sigma_X$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by some nice topology then we may get something nice, but my guess is that in general it may not be the case.

Comment: Yes, you need extra assumptions on $\mathrm{X}$ and $\Sigma.$ However, note that the larger the space, the smaller its dual; the larger the set of functions, the larger is the weakest topology making all of them continuous. The set of bounded measurable function certainly is enormous (and its weak topology I would expect to be quite sizable too, maybe the power set even). (In fact, the existence of non bounded measurable functions is independent of the ZF setting and you need axiom of Choice to prove it.)

Comment: @WilliamM. regarding your last point: I used to think that $\mathrm{id}_\Bbb N:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is Borel-measurable , unbounded and we do not need to use AC to prove its existence

Comment: @llya Yes actually even showing for a vector space that there exists a linear functional on it is not in general doable without the axiom of choice, in my particular example the integration of bounded measurable functions is a natural choice for linear functional and that is why I picked this one. I am trying to think about representation of points as measure on extreme points within that framework were we don't have compactness in general, it feels like some results can generalize.

Comment: @Ilya I meant non-measurable, not non-bounded. Clearly a non-measurable function exists iff there exists a non-measurable set, and the indicator is automatically bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a complete answer yet, but too big to fit a comment. As @Willam M. mentioned, usually one works with a topology generated by bounded continuous maps.

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called a [standard Borel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space) if it is homeomorphic to a Borel subset of a Polish (complete separable metrizable) space. A space of all probability measures on $X$ endowed with a weak topology (as you've described) is a Borel space itself, see e.g. *D. Bertsekas and S. Shreve. Stochastic optimal control: The discrete time case, Corollary 7.25.1*.

Apologies for a perhaps not very canonical reference, but during my PhD time all necessary facts on the topic we were easily finding in the aforementioned book. So definitely to find an example you are interested in one should look into non-separable base spaces $X$. I'm pretty sure such examples one can find in either

1. Classical descriptive set theory by Kechris, or
2. Probability Measure on Metric Spaces by Parthasarathy

In the second book Lemma 6.1 states that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\{\delta_x,x\in X\} \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$, a topological subspace of probability measure space endowed with weak convergence. As a result, in Theorem 6.2 it is used to show that if $\mathcal P(X)$ is separable, then so is $X$. Theorem 6.4 states that $\mathcal P(X)$ is compact if and only if $X$ itself is.

For your case of bounded measurable functions generated topology I would suggest working with the fact that $p(\{x\})$ must be a continuous function for each point $\{x\}\in X$.